# Can't use ltree data type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ltree

According to https://dzone.com/articles/installing-the-postgres-ltree-extension, ltree is installed and enabled on my computer. But when I try to make a table with a column of type `ltree` in Postbird, it says 'type "ltree" does not exist'. This makes no sense. Please help.

Comment: Is the schema it is installed into in your search_path?

Answer (score 0):

Only execute this command in psql or some postgresql's sql client:

```
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```